# How to used Spring Cloud Contract WireMock

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, wiremock

I am taking reference of the doc at https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.1.2.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_wiremock.html

Here I am not able to understand the nature of Service -

```
   // A service that calls out over HTTP
@Autowired
private Service service;
```

Can anyone please help?

My understanding is it's the controller part where endpoint is mapped. Or is it the 3rd party call?

Comment: Do you mean in general or just in that case? Are you familiar with MVC?

Comment: Yes I know MVC but this spring-contract-wiremock is new for me